# FAIL_TO_RETRIEVE_UPDATE error (Creatives V2 API)

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm having some issues with posting creatives through LinkedIn API.
That's a question purely for LinkedIn engineers, as I'm sure it's not the code issue. The problem seems to be happening during bulk-posting Campaigns with associated Creatives. Using `Thread.Sleep` / `await Task.Delay` methods and Synchronous run do not help. The error is not descriptive at all, but I have crossed off the bad request and code error reasons. It's definitely an API problem. I'd like to have more insights on the number of calls I can make to the server and how often can I make those, but it doesn't seem to be related to that either. I tried debugging and waiting 10-20 seconds before posting a Creative.

What I'm doing through the API is below:

1. Posting multiple Shares,
2. Posting multiple Campaigns,
3. Posting multiple Creatives (associating relevant Share urn and Campaign urn to it)

Let me add, that I have made sure that by the time I'm trying to post a Creative it does have both referenced shares' ID and referenced campaigns' ID.

The error message:

> {"message":"Validation failed because [{reason=FAIL_TO_RETRIEVE_UPDATE, field=reference, batchIndex=0, type=REMOTE_OPERATION_FAILED, message=Fail to retrieve update. Could be a temporary failure. Reference , parameters={value=, key=}}]","status":400}

Comment: can you share some detailed info about what you are doing right now? As example are you able to repro the scenario with API call and share them?

Comment: I'm managing multiple clients LinkedIn accounts and for my purpose, I require to post those in bulk (through an Excel spreadsheet). I've written a Microservice, based on LinkedIn API. One of my apps is using this Microservice to post multiple campaigs/shares/creatives. I can't give you any data to work with, unfortunately. Are you aware what's the resource level throttle limit for calls Campaign/Share/Creative APIs is?

Comment: Also, how often those calls can be made for GET/POST requests?

Comment: Also if you made the same operations for a sigle share?

Comment: What do you mean? In my understanding share can be referenced by multiple creatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, please have a look at the following work-around this issue:

I've introduced some retry logic coupled with `await Task.Delay()` method, which seems to be helping a little and if it fails with the above error, 4-5 retries usually is enough to proceed.

```
public async Task<string> PostTheContentAsync(HttpClient httpClient, object campaignManagerObject, string reqUrl, int retriesRemaining = 5)
{
    try
    {
        ByteArrayContent byteContent = CreateByteArrayContent(campaignManagerObject);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(reqUrl, byteContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        IEnumerable<string> headerValue = response.Headers.GetValues("X-LinkedIn-Id");
        return headerValue.First();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (retriesRemaining > 0) //and exception is temporary
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return await PostTheContentAsync(httpClient, campaignManagerObject, reqUrl, retriesRemaining - 1);
        }
        throw new Exception($"Error while posting the content of {campaignManagerObject.GetType()} for URL: {reqUrl} in {nameof(ManagementBaseClass)}, {nameof(PostTheContentAsync)}.");
    }
}
```